# How to change my total input value at the same time as my item input values change

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble getting my grandTotal value to update at the same time as my item input values change. The grandTotal updates only when I add another item to the cart. How do I get my grandTotal  to update without adding an item? I've tried putting my grandTotal variable in the quantity change event block but the total only adds and not subtracts every time the qty changes. I've also tried switching the event listener to 'change' instead of 'click but still have the same problem.

```
    
     let grandTotal = 0;
  let addBtn;
  let subBtn;
  let cartElements;
  let parsed;
  for(let i = 0; i < cartElement.length; i++){
    cartElements = cartElement[i];
    quantities = qtyElement[i];
    prices = priceElement[i];
    addBtn = addBtns[i];
    subBtn = subBtns[i];
    parsed = parseFloat(prices.value);
    grandTotal += parsed;
  }
  cartElements.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      let buttonClicked = e.target;
      if(buttonClicked.innerText === "+"){
        quantities.value++;
        prices.value = quantities.value * price;
      } if(buttonClicked.innerText === "-"){
        quantities.value--;
        prices.value = quantities.value * price;
      } 
    });
  grandTotalInput.value = grandTotal;
 }
<form class="cart-form">
  <h1>shopping cart</h1>
     
  
  </form>
<form id="totalContainer">
  
</form> 
<div class="grandTotal">
  <input name="grandTotalInput" id="grandTotalInput" type="number" disabled="">
</div>
```

Comment: 200 lines of code, that's not really what you can call minimal code please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You would need to update the grandtotal inside this function :

```js
quantities.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let qty = parseFloat(quantities.value);
    prices.value = qty * price;
});
```

Comment: I have tried that solution but then the total amount keeps increasing instead of doing both, increasing and decreasing, when I click up/down accordingly.

Comment: @ChristopherAguilar You would need to pass in the type of action to the function `function(type)` the if the type is `add` you increment, else you decrement. Do you understand?

Comment: I think I understand, I will try and figure it out and let you know. Thank you

Comment: @ChristopherAguilar Alrighty. If it does work, you can mark this as the correct answer

Comment: Im still  working on it, I found a solution that requires adding increment and decrement buttons so that I can increase and decrease the value. I should be able to get it done tomorrow.

Comment: Nice. I assumed you had both increment & decrement buttons already

Comment: Okay, I added the increment and decrement buttons. I have tried numerous ways to get my grandTotal to add/sub as my values change. I am able to get a grandTotal update only as I add to the cart. I know the solution is probably in my grasp, but I am just not seeing it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ive edited my code to what I have now above.